# How to save initial object to database that has a self reference in Django

Tags: django, self-reference

Let's say I have a custom Django model User with a self-reference:

```
Class User(models.Model)
    name=models.CharField(max_length=80)
    .
    .
    .
    user_created = models.ForeignKey(
        'self',     
        on_delete=models.PROTECT,
    )
```

As you can see, I want the user_created field to have a NOT NULL constraint. Not surprisingly, if I try to create the first ever user without a user_created reference like so...

```
User.objects.create(name='Bob') <-- Remember I'm the first ever user in the DB
```

I get:

```
django.db.utils.IntegrityError: null value in column "user_created" violates not-null constraint
```

I get why Django throws this error. I have declared a NOT NULL CONSTRAINT for the user_created field, but I can't provide anything because no other user currently exists in the database.

I have previously dealt with this by first creating a User object, and then applying the Not Null constraint, which works fine except when I run tests. When I run tests Django creates a new database and there is no way for me to supply the first user to that test database.

I worked around this by creating a CustomTestRunner(DiscoverRunner) that drops the constraint before the test database is created, which also works fine. However, I was wondering if anyone else out there ran into this problem and found a better solution.

Is there something I'm missing here? Thanks in advance!

UPDATE:

I figured it out! If you run into this and are using Postgres you can look at deferring constraints. You can set the validation CONTRAINT to initially deferred, which allows you to create an item with a cyclic relation to itself before any items exist.

I should not that normally Django does this for you automatically, but I was working with legacy databases so I had to defer constraints manually in some cases.

[Check Postgres docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/sql-set-constraints.html#:%7E:text=DEFERRED%20constraints%20are%20not%20checked,INITIALLY%20IMMEDIATE%2C%20or%20NOT%20DEFERRABLE.)

Comment: Instead of using `User.create(name='Bob')` use `User.objects.create(name='Bob')` which is the default model Manager.

Comment: Sorry, that was a typo. I meant to write User.objects.create(name='Bob') in my question. I am using that in my code

Comment: Do you have a circular relationship among users? Otherwise the *first* user must have a `NULL` relationship, no?

Comment: User has a cyclic foreign key to itself. So I wanted to be able to create a User1 with a relationship to User1. I found out that this can be done with Postgres by Defering contraints.